# Desktop loses color setting (suddenly everything is yellow-ish)

Tags: nvidia, colors

I installed the nvidia drivers on ubuntu 17.10.
Now I have the problem that the color settings suddenly change and everything looks yellow-ish.

When I use nvidia-settings and 'Reset Hardware Defaults' everything looks normal. But a few minutes later, out of a sudden, the settings flip back and everything look yellow-ish again.

Does anybody have a clue how I cloud find out what is causing this?

Comment: Check your display settings if the NightLight or something like that is enabled as it is used to turn down the blue light when it gets dark out.

Answer (score 2):

It was in fact the Night Light settings. Thanks Terrance.

After turning off **Settings > Devices > Displays > Night Light** everything looks normal (and stayed that way).